# What does it mean for an integer to be congruent to 1 $\pmod {n}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

This keeps coming up in Sylow proofs.

Eg: **By Sylow's theorem, the number of subgroups of order 5 must divide 45, and must be congruent to 1 modulo 5; the only possibility is that there is a single group of order 5.**

Subgroups of order 5 must divide 45 by Lagrange's theorem, and they need to divide the index of the subgroup in G by Sylow's theorems. That means, we can have 1 or 5 subgroups of order 5, no? So why 1? I assume its something im missing with the "congruent" part.

Comment: It means it’s one more than a multiple of $5$ (i.e., it’s $1$ or $6$ or $11$ or $16$ or $21$ or ...)

Comment: Integers $a,b$ are congruent mod $n$ if $a-b$ is divisible by $n$. Equivalently, this means that $a$ and $b$ leave the same remainder when we divide them by $n$. The notation is $a\equiv b$(mod $n$)

Comment: I think the OP's question is rather "why must the number of subgroups of order $5$ be congruent to $1$ modulo $5$ ?" than "what does to be congruent to $1$ modulo $5$ mean ?".

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Take a look at both the title and the question itself. Also, why would OP ask about how to prove the third Sylow theorem? The proof appears in any book about group theory.

Comment: @Mark Well, yeah. But I would be a little bit surprised to meet someone dealing with Sylow's theorems without knowing what a congruence is...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Actually, this happens. You don't need to know a lot about mathematics in order to learn basic group theory. If OP learns it from some book then surely the group $\mathbb{Z_n}$ should have appeared as an example, but maybe they just didn't use the term "congruent".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose the number of Sylow-$5$ subgroup is $n$. As $n$ is congruent to $1$ mod $5$ , it's should be of the form $5k+1$. Now as $5k+1$ must divide $45= 5×9$ i.e must divide $9$ ( as it's co prime to $5$) , the only possibility of $k$ is $0$, hence therefore $n$ has only the value $1$.

Comment: Welcome to the forum. Please use MathJax when you write here. Here is a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: good scoring Sweta!

Answer (score 3):

Observe that the divisors of $45$ are $1$, $3$, $5$, $9$ and $15$, but $5\nmid (3-1)$, $5\nmid (5-1)$, $5\nmid (9-1)$ and $5\nmid (15-1)$.